# alternative to eval('$array_test = array('.$test.');')

Tags: php, arrays, type-conversion, eval

I'm looking for an alternative to

```
$test = "1=>'msg_test1',3=>'msg_test2',9=>'msg_test3'";
eval('$array_test = array('.$test.');');
```

does anyone have an idea how i can make it to have an array in a secure way from a string?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Any reason for not using a data-exchange format like JSON (or XML, or SEN or any other known format)?

Comment: If eval is your best option you're probably doing it wrong

Comment: Notice that `eval` = `evil` :)

Comment: It's probably XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please tell us what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Missing quotes in $test mean that it wouldn't be valid

Comment: of course, if i could, i would do it like that, but datas are coming "1=>'msg_test1,3=>'msg_test2,9=>'msg_test3'" like from ajax... i know eval is not good, that's why i m looking for another way...

Comment: Where is the data originating from? Can you change the source (presumably not)? That isn't even a valid format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse it manually with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like so:

```
$test = "1=>'msg_test1,3=>'msg_test2,9=>'msg_test3'";

$array_test = array();
foreach(explode(',', substr($test, 0, -1)) as $row)
{
    $split = explode('=>\'', $row);
    $array_test[$split[0]] = $split[1];
}

var_dump($array_test);
```

Produces:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => string 'msg_test1' (length=9)
  3 => string 'msg_test2' (length=9)
  9 => string 'msg_test3' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then you cshould format your string like this

`$test = "value1,value2,value2";`

Then proceed with and explode

`$array_test = explode(',', $test);`

your array

```
$array_test = array(
    '1' => 'value1'
    '2' => 'value2'
    '3' => 'value3'
);
```